# How can I present a nested-list object in an .Rmd file?

Tags: json, linked-list, nested

I am writing a `myFile.Rmd` file, and I want to display a list (`class`) from a JSON file at a certain point. However, when I run the code:

```
if(!require(httr)){
  install.packages("httr")
  library(httr)
}
if(!require(jsonlite)){
  install.packages("jsonlite")
  library(jsonlite)
}
myLink <- GET("https://ws-ext.it.auth.gr/open/getUgradHistStatus")
con1 <- myLink$content
viewable <- fromJSON(rawToChar(con1))
knitr::kable(viewable) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "200px")
```

I get the following error message:

`Error in matrix(body_rows, ncol = n_cols, byrow = TRUE) :  data is too long`

How can I nicely present this list?